# DnsServiceRegister API issue

Tags: winapi, dns

I'm trying to use the Windows 10+ API [DnsServiceRegister](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsserviceregister) to register a web server to be discoverable.

```
       DNS_SERVICE_REGISTER_REQUEST rd = {};           
       DNS_SERVICE_INSTANCE di = {};
       rd.pServiceInstance = &di;
       rd.unicastEnabled =  0;
       di.pszInstanceName = L"Remote Control._http._tcp.local";
       di.pszHostName = L"192.168.10.6";
       IP4_ADDRESS i4 = {};
       InetPton(AF_INET, L"192.168.10.6", (void*)&i4);
       di.ip4Address = &i4;

       di.wPort = (WORD)12345;
       rd.Version = DNS_QUERY_REQUEST_VERSION1;
       rd.pRegisterCompletionCallback = [](DWORD Status,
           PVOID pQueryContext,
           PDNS_SERVICE_INSTANCE pInstance)
       {
           nop();
       };
       DnsServiceRegister(&rd, 0);
```

The call succeeds (return value DNS_REQUEST_PENDING as per documentation) and after a while, my callback is called with status = 0 (Success?). However, no UPnP tools detect my service.
When I set unicast to 1, status is 9002 (error).

What am I missing in using this API?

Edit: When the callback is called, the pInstance parameter there points to a DNS_SERVICE_INSTANCE with ip4Address and ip6Address null pointers. Why?

Edit: It's discoverable by using DnsServiceBrowse(). But UPnP scan tools don't discover it.

Comment: *"Anyone has used successfully this new API?"* is not a useful question. Please see [ask].

Comment: What `DWORD` value is `DnsServiceRegister()` itself returning? Does it return `9506` (`DNS_REQUEST_PENDING`), or something else? Status code `9002` is `DNS_ERROR_RCODE_SERVER_FAILURE`.

Comment: You are not setting the `rd.Version` field to `DNS_QUERY_REQUEST_VERSION1` (1), like the documentation says to do.  You are setting it to `0` instead, when you zero-initialize `rd`.

Comment: `rd.Version = DNS_QUERY_REQUEST_VERSION1;`...

Comment: I edited, it calls my callback with status 0 but the ipv4 is null.

Comment: `pszInstanceName` is documented as being a fully qualified domain name; your value has a space in it, which is not valid.

Comment: @Luke, thanks, but that made no difference. Still same result.

Answer (score 0):

di.pszHostName = L"192.168.10.6";

is not a valid hostname.  It needs to be a string and end in .local.

I was having the same issue and I copied your code snippet to test.  It works if the host name is a normal name ending in .local.